# Google Spread sheet-pulling down formulas is returning an error message

Tags: google-spreadsheets

In Google Sheets, I need a formula that will add columns C-J and give me the total in column M.

I entered `=SUM(C5:J5)` as a function in cell M5

When I go to drag it down (using the lower right hand edge of the cell) so that each line will have the same formula specific for that line, it gives me the error message:

> This operation is not permitted because it would alter the structure of this table.

Howe can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the browser you using because I am trying to replicate the issue on my side using Fire Fox and it seems to be working fine, just takes a bit of time for the formulas to load when they are dragged.

Perhaps try open  your spreadsheet in another browser.